# A property on an object has data assigned to it, but returns undefied when it tries to access that property

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
[
  {
    _id: 610be2c,
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '600333',
    receiver: 5fea6e,
  },
  {
    _id: 610be2d,
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '6003123',
    receiver: 608ffae,
  }
] 


Message.find({}, function(err, users) {
        
 
        if (users) {
            users.forEach(function(user) {
                console.log(`${user.receiver}`, 'receiver');
        });
});
```

The result in console.log for `user.receiver`:

```
undefined receiver
undefined receiver
```

I tried for `user._id, user.sender` and everything is ok.
For `user.receiver` it returns `undefined`, although when I get the above two objects from the database I can see two objects and for the `receiver` property the data is attached.
I tried to use `user.receiver.toString()` but I get an error:
`Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Comment: Don't the _id and receiver values have to be strings too: eg `receiver: '5fea6e'`?

Comment: @Andy `_Id` is added by the mongodb database automatically. "Receiver" is supposed to be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the value of `receiver` is not a string instead it's something `608ffae` which JS reads as a variable(that might not be the case) and since it's not defined or declared it returns `undefined`:

Update:

```
[
  {
    _id: 610be2c,
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '600333',
    receiver: '5fea6e',
  },
  {
    _id: 610be2d,
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '6003123',
    receiver: '608ffae',
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

update to this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 610be2c,
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '600333',
    receiver: '5fea6e',
  },
  {
    _id: 610be2d,
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '6003123',
    receiver: '608ffae',
  }
]
```